# wget on a picture generated by a function php

Tags: php, shell, wget

I have this exec triggered at some if condition :

```
exec('( [ ! -e "ha45_temp" ] && touch ha45_temp && wget http://localhost/index.php/Montor/makeApiCameraPrintscreen?id='.$insert_id .' -O ./images/'. $insert_id.' > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 30 && rm ha45_temp ) > /dev/null 2>&1 &');
```

I'm calling makeApiCameraPrintscreen method from my main controller, and direct its output to this path : -O ./images/ with the name of the $insert_id(I hold in that var a unique id to name the pictures)

This is the method:

```
public function makeApiCameraPrintscreen(){
    $imagename = $this->input->get('id', TRUE);
    $datasidget = $this->curl->simple_get('somepictureapi');
    $datasid = json_decode($datasidget,true);
    $data_sid =  $datasid['data']['sid'];
    $reqUrl = "somepictureapi";
    $imageencode = $this->curl->simple_get($reqUrl);
    $this->output->set_content_type('jpeg');
    $this->output->set_output($imageencode);

    }
```

My problem is that my wget saves a binary octet stream file( that binary is the from the image thou, but it's not in proper extension).

```
�t?���q��H�*�ӏ��m�}"�Vo�k��c(���䢐T�m첟
```

This is a example of a line. Now thing is I'm not sure that I will get the pictures in jpeg format (content-type), but I try'ed thou with jpg/png same output.

What I want to do is to save the picture from my wget in a proper format so that I can open it.

PS1. for Mark:

```
00000000: 0aff d8ff fe00 104c 6176 6335 362e 3630  .......Lavc56.60
00000010: 2e31 3030 00ff db00 4300 080a 0a0b 0a0b  .100....C.......
00000020: 0d0d 0d0d 0d0d 100f 1010 1010 1010 1010  ................
00000030: 1010 1012 1212 1515 1512 1212 1010 1212  ................
00000040: 1414 1515 1717 1715 1515 1517 1719 1919  ................
00000050: 1e1e 1c1c 2323 242b 2b33 ffc4 01a2 0000  ....##$++3......
00000060: 0105 0101 0101 0101 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000070: 0102 0304 0506 0708 090a 0b01 0003 0101  ................
00000080: 0101 0101 0101 0100 0000 0000 0001 0203  ................
00000090: 0405 0607 0809 0a0b 1000 0201 0303 0204  ................
```

Comment: Did you try to save all the output into a jpg file ? This should works

Comment: Yes, I did stated in my post ''but I try'ed thou with jpg/png same output''

Comment: Try running `xxd YourImage | head -10` and clicking `edit` under your question and copying & pasting in the output - then we can see what the data looks like in hex and tell you.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Ok, done that.

Comment: I think you have a superfluous linefeed (`0a`) at the start of your image - somewhere in your PHP before you output the image, you are outputting a linefeed first.

Comment: As a quick test, remove the first byte with `dd if=YourImage bs=1 skip=1 > newImage.jpg`

Comment: Wow nice, now I can see the image, but how do modify my code in order to direct output that ?

Comment: Something in your PHP is generating an extra linefeed character before you send the image - maybe in `set_content_type()` - which I cannot see. There must be a `printf` or an `echo` or something in your code somewhere.